# Mystery padding in table cells with image

Tags: html

I hate to admit this: I'm building a complicated, but gmail-friendly HTML email blast (inline styling). Anyway, it's a game of tables and split images, and I've seemed to have forgotten all my 1995 table mojo.

http://www.highgatecross.com/development/tables/

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td><img src="skyline.jpg" alt=""></td>
        <td><img src="skyline-02.jpg" alt=""></td>
        <td><img src="skyline-03.jpg" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><img src="skyline-04.jpg" alt=""></td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

I have a mystery 4-pixel "padding" below each images (the DOM panel in Firebug shows a cell "clientHeight" 4 pixels greater than my images).

I have tried every combination of deprecated HTML styling (heights, etc.) and CSS and no joy.

So, simply, how do I rid the 4 pixels and close the gap between rows?

Comment: This can be handy when playing with tables http://www.somacon.com/p141.php though it's more for styling tables with CSS

Answer (score 51):

**Just use** `style="display: block"` **on the image.**

**Problem solved.**

Comment: A simple explenation would be great. Which display-attribute value does the image have by default?

Comment: Images are inline by default.

Answer (score 21):

I should have checked StackOverflow first!

Either:

```
<img src="some.jpg" style="display: block" />
```

or

```
<img src="some.jpg" style="vertical-align: bottom" />
```

will eliminate the 4 pixels under the image in a table cell.

Answer (score 13):

I fiddled around with a number of properties and it appears that setting `line-height: 0` removes the gap.

Comment: On which tag do you apply this ?

Answer (score 4):

Another way to fix is to add `font-size: 0` on the `td`.

Comment: This isn't a good solution: aside from being potentially confusing if you try to add some text inside the cell, this might not work if the user-agent has a minimum font size set.